# Sharing Google Analytics with Clients

Tags: google-analytics, google-apps

We develop websites for clients and want to give them access to their site analytics.

Not all our clients have their own google accounts, and moreover we want a unified system where multiple people at a client organization can have access to their site's analytics.

At first I thought I would set up an analytics account under our company's google apps account, and add our clients as users with varying access.  However, I've just discovered that Google Analytics works only with personal google accounts- NOT with Google Apps accounts?!

> You can only access Analytics reports
>   using a valid Google Accounts email
>   address. You cannot sign in to
>   Analytics with an email address hosted
>   by Google Apps.
>   ([See here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts.html#googleAccounts))

That leaves us with two unappealing options:

1. Add clients as users to the Google Analytics associated with my personal google account.
2. Create personal google accounts for each client organization we want to set up with analytics.

Does anyone have a better approach to this?

Thanks--

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately not really -- the one place where GA still falls flat is that you can't transport data between accounts.

That said, just giving clients access to particular google analytics sites works very transparently -- I don't even think they see what the "master" account is. And, for future accounts and clients, I'd generally recommend setting them up with their own accounts. You can always make sure to give your user account administrative access to update stuff, but they can feel good that the client owns their own data.

Answer (score 3):

If you need your clients to be able to log into Google Analytics then they will need a Google account. However, it's pretty easy for you or them to set one up. Once it's done you can give them report-only access to just the profiles for their own websites.

Other than that you would need to use the Google Analytics API to pull the data out and put it into your own system where clients could check their stats.

Comment: I think its worth mentioning here that you are only able to create a limited number of Google Accounts per IP address. I used to do this for my clients but could only make about 30 accounts before I couldn't make any more.

Comment: @MeltingDog That's a good point and one which prevents me from moving all my clients onto GA

Comment: I'm not sure about there being a hard limit like that, but I can see why Google might have a security feature to stop too many accounts being created at once. If you're using AdWords then you could try to contact your rep, as there might be a way they can help; if you have a valid reason to be creating accounts, then I don't think they would want to stop you from using their product.

Answer (score 0):

Megalytic http://megalytic.com is a tool that enables you to share select Google Analytics charts with clients without you having to give them access to the underlying GA profiles.

You simply assign clients a username and password.

Also works with Twitter and Facebook Insights.

See a demo here: http://blog.megalytic.com/embedded-client-pages and a tutorial here: https://megalytic.zendesk.com/entries/23425657-Client-Pages

Disclaimer:  I am a founder of Megalytic.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but check there is a way to do this and it's pretty simple, just follow the instructions provided in the link.

http://webavenue.com.au/allow-multiple-people-access-to-your-google-analytics/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com) (I work with them).  Our specialty is implementing Google Analytics dashboards for situations exactly like this.  Our dashboards can be implemented directly into backend management areas (i.e. secure area).  No reason to go to a 3rd party site or to wait for emailed reports.  There is no report generation latency: data is fetched quickly using the Google Analytics API once client requests to see their dashboard.

We support many different scenarios:

- Individual clients have their own Google Analytics account.  Web hosting company injects the tracking code into client's web pages.  Client will be directed to a one time Google Analytics authorization to allow us to access their data.
- Web Hosting company maintains all GA profiles under a single GA Account.   New GA profile must be created for each new client.
- Individual clients "share" their account access with Web Hosting company's master account.
- Web Hosting company utilizes a single GA profile.  Through the use of custom variables they can segment different users.  Example: tracking different authors performance on a Blog.